# display:none and scrolling text

Tags: html, css

There is a conflict between display:none and scrolling text.  What can I use instead of using display:none?

```
<div id="side_forums_pane" class="side_pane" style=" height:350px;width:260px">
   <div class="jscroller2_up jscroller2_speed-19 jscroller2_mousemove" style="height:250px;width:260px;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are allowed to use the body of the question to **ask an actual question**

Comment: @astander: It was hidden due to SO interpreting the text as HTML. (Not that this question was clear, but it was a new user that ended up confounded by the system and then yelled at...)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the element to be invisible, you can apply this class to it

```
.invisible_class {
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

more info [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)

you can also try `visibility: hidden;`

note: both methods hide the element but it will still occupy the space it used to